# Vb.net help me with regex please

Tags: regex, vb.net, html-parsing

I havent worked with regex before... But I need to parse values in about 500 urls and  I need regex for automate it.

Each site contains about 10 values, I need to separate them to own list.

1.

```
<td width="78" style="padding-left:9px;" align="left"><a style="font-weight:bold;color:#E93393;" href="/meanings/Example1.html">Example1</a> </td>
```

2.

```
<td width="78" style="padding-left:9px;" align="left"><a style="font-weight:bold;color:#004EFF;" href="/meanings/Example2.html">Example2</a> </td>
```

So, I need to get those 2 values to separate list. It should look for color code to determine in which list value goes.

Could somebody help me? :)

Comment: htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I don't see what exactly you need. What exactly do you need to parse, what is the output value you expect, what is the input?

Answer (score 2):

**NO..NO..NO..**

Regex doesnt work for parsing HTML files..

HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format..

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Could you give example of how to use it?